# Taylor Series based Sin() implementation using templates C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on an implementation of the sin() function based on the taylor series using templates. My code so far goes as follows:

```
template<unsigned I>
struct factorial{
    enum{  
    value = I * factorial<I -1>::value
    };
};
template<>
struct factorial<0>
{
    enum{ value = 1};
};
template<unsigned pow>
inline double power(double const& value){
    return value * power<pow-1>(value);
}
template<>
inline double power<1>(double const& value){
    return value;
}
template <unsigned term>
inline double taylor_sine_term(double const& x) {
    return (power<term>(-1) / factorial<(2*term)+1>::value) * power<(2*term)+1>(x);
}
```

The issue I am having is creating the function to use the `taylor_sine_term` function to expand the series for N number of terms.The function would be functionally equivalent to the following.

```
template<unsigned terms>
inline double taylor_sine(double const& x){
    return taylor_sine_term<1>(x)+taylor_sine_term<2>(x) + ... + taylor_sine_term<terms>(x);
}
```

Basically I need to figure out a way to generate a sequence of integer constants that can be used as the term number template parameter in the `taylor_sine_term` function for N number of terms and sum them all together. The result will expand into the full taylor series for N number of terms. The problem is I don't know where to start.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you wrote the other ones: a recursive case and a base case:

```
template<unsigned terms>
inline double taylor_sine(double const& x) {
    return taylor_sine_term<terms>(x) + // current term
           taylor_sine<terms-1>(x);     // rest of terms
}

template <>
inline double taylor_sine<0>(const double& x) {
    return taylor_sine_term<0>(x);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the index sequence trick to get all of them:

```
template <unsigned terms>
inline double taylor_sine(double const& x) {
    return taylor_sine(x, std::make_index_sequence<terms+1>{});
}

template <unsigned terms, size_t... Is>
inline double taylor_sine(const double& x, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
    double res = 0.0;
    for (double t : {taylor_sine_term<Is>(x)...}) {
        res += t;
    }
    return res;

    /* or in C++17
    return (taylor_sine_term<Is>(x) + ...);
    */
}
```

Note that you should change your base case on `power` to be `power<0>`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a recursively defined template

```
template<unsigned terms>
inline double taylor_sine(double const& x){
    return taylor_sine<terms-1>(x)+taylor_sine_term<terms>(x);
}
```

Then you would **want** to specialize for either 0 or 1 to terminate.  But I think you can't specialize the function template, so you would need to bury that all in a functor template, which you can specialize.